# Aligning buttons to buttom of screen LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have this layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/office_girl" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/greetingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi Boss,"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dailyStatusTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="What to say if someone call?" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
<!--         android:layout_gravity="center" -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/suto_sms_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:hint="Text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_phone_status"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone Status"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_phone_status"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_busy_until"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="until"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        <Button
            android:enabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_set_date_and_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/set_time" />
        <TextView
                android:enabled="true"
                android:id="@+id/text_date_and_time"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/button_confirm" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is part of the output:

[image]

**My question is how to align my Confirm and Cancel buttons (last part of the xml) to buttom of the screen?**

I saw examples of how it can be done using relative layout, but my xml is quite big and i dont want to have to change it to relative layout as it will mean lots of work.

Thanks.

Comment: try with RelativeLAyout.

Comment: @amitsingh the OP said he has seen answers saying to use `RelativeLayout` but he doesn't want to change everything. With that said, @Michael A, I think it would be worth it to switch to `RelativeLayout` because I think that's the only way you will get exactly what you need to work with different screens, etc. If this is your whole layout then it won't be hard to change. Add `android:layout_below="@idToBeBelow"` to each and give each child `LinearLayuot` an `id`. Not much more to it

Comment: i was stuck with the same problem and i used layout_wieght=0.75 for the top and din't specify anything for the bottom element. And it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/greetingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi Boss,"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dailyStatusTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="What to say if someone call?" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- android:layout_gravity="center" -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/suto_sms_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:hint="Text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_phone_status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Phone Status"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_phone_status"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_busy_until"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="until"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_set_date_and_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="set_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_date_and_time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="confirm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here your using lot of LinearLayouts but personally i recommend you to try out [relativelayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute on the buttons as well as their containing `LinearLayout`.

Comment: bottom `gravity` doesn't work for a vertically aligned `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in second last LinearLayout and

```
android:layout_weight="0"
```

in last LinearLayout. Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy to use the RelativeLayout, because you can be very smart about it. For example, wrap it around everything, so that your current parent linear layout will be the first child, end put the linear layout with the buttons at outside of the current parent with the parameter alignParentBottom

Please see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/greetingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi Boss,"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dailyStatusTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="What to say if someone call?" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!--         android:layout_gravity="center" -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/suto_sms_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:hint="Text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_phone_status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Status"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_phone_status"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_busy_until"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="until"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <Button
            android:enabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_set_date_and_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="set_time" />
        <TextView
            android:enabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/text_date_and_time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="confirm" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```